# help finding car purchased via cell phone that I can not find in garage or impound

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I bought a car off the cell phone and used it once on a mission but it isn't at my garage and impound and it wasn't there. how can I find it?

Comment: Online or story? And what exactly did you buy? Pegasus cars in online are essentially rentals.

Comment: story. and I bought a Lamborghini off of Michael cell phone

Comment: I believe in story mode, because they have story based personal vehicles, any car that isn't stored in a garage is lost. But I would need to confirm.